# Using normalized vectors to store heading

Tags: c#, vector, xna, game-physics

I'm making a simple game in C#/XNA. My actors store the direction in which they intend to go as a `Vector2`. At each update cycle, I normalize the heading (because of the way it's set can lead to different lengths) and add `heading*Speed` to position to move the actor.

This seems inelegant. Logically, a direction has no length, it is of unit length by definition. Practically, the constant normalization has trivial extraneous computational cost.

1. Is there a `NormalizedVector2` in XNA?
2. How do I go about creating one which is compatible with XNA's `Vector2` (ie can be added to it and so on)? Extend `Vector2` and override the `Length` property?
3. Are there larger conceptual problems with how I am trying to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Although it can be thought that direction by itself has no magnitude, a velocity vector does. A velocity vector contains both speed and direction and it is convenient to represent both of those data in a single vector structure. A very easy way to combine a heading and a speed is to start with a unit length heading like your doing. Utilizing that velocity vector which effectively contains two bits of data is an elegant thing.

Answer (score 2):

1. No.  The only 2D vector is `Vector2` in XNA.
2. You can't.  Since `Vector2` is a `struct`, you can't sbuclass it.  You could make your own type and provide a method to *convert* it into a `Vector2` (by creating a new `Vector2`), however.

Realistically, I suspect your current approach (using `Vector2` and just calling [Normalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.normalize.aspx) is likely the best approach.  If you are really worried about many calls, use [the overload which uses `ref` and `out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198257.aspx) for the parameters, as it's slightly more efficient.

Comment: It's such a tiny function that, unless you're writing a particle or physics engine, and doing careful profiling (they're, like, really tiny!), it doesn't really matter which one you choose. But, for what it's worth, I thought I'd verify your answer. And you're quite right, the other two overloads are both about 25% slower (x86 .NET 4.0).

Comment: Actually I (somewhat) take that back. If you're normalizing a vector "in place", then the `Normalize()` that works on `this` is the same speed as the `static` one that takes references. Profiling these suckers is tricky ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Not that I'm aware of
2. As stated, Vector cannot be subclassed, but you could create a Direction class which handles the computation and which can be parsed to a Vector2 or just have a Vector proerpty.
3. I would just use an unitary vector and rotate it using a matrix. In terms of performance, it avoids a division which is usually a slow operation.
   Even in term of logic, it is more common express a direction as a 30° to the left, rather than x + y.

Comment: Normalizing a vector is 2 multiplications, an addition, a square root, and a division. **But** rotating a vector with a matrix is *lots* of additions and multiplications, plus a couple of trig operations. I bet the matrix rotation is *way* slower. You could do it without the matrix - I bet it's still not a performance win. Expressing directions as normalized vectors is actually extremely common.

Answer (score -2):

Am i missing something? A normalized vector is just a vector where x + y totals 1 and points into a direction. It has no length, like any vector has.

You can store a normalized vector just in a vector of the same type. And of course you need to update it when you need to change the direction of something.

Its a fairly simple concept described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.normalize.aspx

Comment: `Vector2` stores magnitude and direction. Magnitude is irrelevant for my purposes and I do not wish to store it. As you can tell from my question, I know how to normalize a vector.